# How to know the total memory (RAM) of system using install script of Install Shield

Tags: installshield

I am using Install Shield 5.5. I would like to know whether is it possible to know the total memory (RAM) of the system using API of install shield? If yes, please let me know how can we do that?

Thanks for help,
Nayan

Comment: InstallShield 5.x has not been supported for years, and doesn't really support any modern versions of Windows. (That's not to say it won't work, but it was written in an era where GB of memory or TB of hard drive were so rare that they may not be reported correctly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michael is right.  You should use a newer tool as that's got to be about 15 years old now.

InstallScript has/had a SysInfo function but I doubt it works today.  You could possibly declare external DLL functions using prototype and UseDLL() calls  to work directly with the Win32 API and/or WMI  classes to get the information but why bother?

Just upgrade to something that uses Windows Installer  ( InstallShield or WiX ) and use the [PhysicalMemory property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370818%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the amount of RAM on the machine.